# Can I just store the result of mmap in an integer?

Tags: c++, linux

I am using mmap and I have code like this:

```
void* mappedRegion;

mappedRegion = mmap( 0, 8192, PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
```

In C++ is a void pointer the correct way to do this?  Why do we need a void pointer anyhow? doesn't mmap just return the address of the new mapping?  Would a int32_t handle that?

Comment: `mmap` returns a `void *`, so that's what you need here, regardless of the language you are using. And of course a `void *` may be 64 bits, so using a shorter integer type would be a very bad idea.

Comment: You can't assume that the address returned is of a fixed bitness if you want portable code

Comment: `mmap` is not a C++11 thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the correct way, and we need a `void*` because that's what `mmap` returns.

Yes, that return-value is "just" a pointer, but there is no guarantee an `int32_t` would be able to hold it after reinterpretation.

BTW: You will need to cast it to the proper type for storing your objects later, as pointer-arithmetic is not possible on incomplete types.

Comment: OK, thanks, I was wondering if somehow the c++11 auto should be used.

Comment: I really would not in this case, though it does not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't mmap just return the address of the new mapping?

Yes.

Addresses are pointers, not integral numbers.